# Problem related to vectors and triangle geometry

Tags: vectors

If O is the circumcenter of $\delta ABC$ and three forces act along OA, OB, OC respectively proportional to BC, CA, AB then show that their resultant passes through the incenter of ABC.

I tried using the law of sines due to the proportionality condition but it did not work.

Any thoughts on how to proceed?

Comment: Can you show your work for the calculation? What is the incenter in vector form? $\quad$ FWIW It should fall out almost immediately.